# Determine tag of tapped UItextView

Tags: ios, xcode

I have many UItextViews in a UIscroll view. When the user presses on a button he should be able to tap on one of these UItextViews, and depending what textview he has touched, the text in it will be chosen. Since my UItextViews number depends on each user, I assign them tags in for of an integer: 1,2,3. Then I use tap gesture gesture to detect the tag of the touched view:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *myLongPressRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(leftSwipe:)];
 //[myLongPressRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp)];
[textname addGestureRecognizer:myLongPressRecognizer];


- (void)leftSwipe:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

id sender;
UITextView *txtChoosen = (UITextView*) sender;

for (UITextView* txt in textnameArray) {

    NSLog(@"%djjjjjjj, %d", txtChoosen.tag, txt.tag);

    if (txt.tag == txtChoosen.tag) {

        txt.layer.borderWidth = 5.0f;
        txt.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
    }else{

        txt.layer.borderWidth = 0.0f;
        txt.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
}}
...
```

My problem is that the txtChoosen.tag is always equal to zero. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured out how to determine the tag:

```
if (txt.tag ==  [(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer view].tag) {

...
```

Basically this is the code to determine it:

```
[(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer view].tag
```